# Manage Groups broken in 4.7.10 (and possible workaround)

Tags: groups, smartgroups, 4.7.10

We upgraded civifrom 4.6.2 to 4.7.10 (on WP) everything worked fine except for accessing the manage groups page. When trying to add a contact to an existing group we got the msg “Error one of the parameters is not of type integer”.

Accessing the 'manage groups' page gave the following error
[image]

The workaround I found through the frontend was to create a new group and also run a search and create a new smartgroup.  It now seems to work fine (fingers crossed)

EDIT:  it worked for all of 5 minutes, displayed the manage groups page first few clicks opening it and then reverted to the same error message. I have tried clearing my cache - no change. Back to the drawing board.

I have also replicated the error on our test system. (upgraded from 4.6.12 to 4.7.10) works fro 5 minutes and then same error.

In addition when in a contact record and opening the smart group section I get a network error. I move to anywhere else in the record and the network error disappears

[image]